# how do I make a paragraph when I am asking a question

Tags: discussion

I am trying to be concise with my questions .  but every time I try to make a paragraph here, it goes ahead and posts before I am finished

Comment: You mean when you press the <enter> key it posts your question? That's odd.

Comment: Is this when you post questions, or comments *(I know it does it for comments - annoying sometimes)*? You can use `<br>` to create a new line if pressing Enter just posts it...

Comment: @Wilf `<br>` is hardly ever useful on a Stack Exchange site. In particular, `<br>` doesn't work in a comment. No HTML works in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is a paragraph.

I added two returns here, so this is another paragraph.

If you aren't able to add paragraph, maybe you should edit your question and tag it as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) + [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) and not as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).